# Connection between Frontend and Backend with Zuul and Eureka

Tags: javascript, java, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have some app on my back and front for him on react.js, i connect directly frontend and backend sides without zuul gateway. How i can connect them with using Zuul?

Comment: Hi Oleg, and welcome to StackOverflow! From what you have written alone, it's very difficult to tell what you are asking. To me, it sounds like you are asking for a beginner's tutorial on Zuul, which which would be off-topic on this site.

Comment: josh long has videos that show how to set up basic things https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q8B6lYhFvE

Comment: i mean, how i can fetch  from my front to back through zuul (front->zuul->back), because now this connection is directly without zuul.